# Connection of JSP with MySQL failed

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, jdbc

OK i am unable to connect my JSP program with MYSQL table to create , retrieve or do anything with program

Using NetBeans 6.8, win XP sp 2, TOMCAT 6, etc...

In NetBeans showing tables connected, already applied MYSQL connector in `C:\apache-tomcat-5.5.33\apache-tomcat-5.5.33\common\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar`

Code I am using to connect is

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Creating Table in DB using JSP</h1>


    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>display data from the table using jsp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
                    /* Create string of connection url within specified
                    format with machine name, port number
                    and database name. Here machine name id localhost
                    and database name is usermaster. */
                    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ipsj";
                    // declare a connection by using Connection interface
                    Connection connection = null;
                    // declare object of Statement interface that is used for
                    // executing sql statements.
                    Statement statement = null;
                    try {
                        // Load JBBC driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver".
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                        /* Create a connection by using getConnection() method
                        that takes parameters of string type connection url, user
                        name and password to connect to database. */
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");

                        /* createStatement() is used for create statement object
                        that is used for sending
                        sql statements to the specified database. */
                        statement = connection.createStatement();
                        // sql query to retrieve values from the secified table.
                        String QueryString = "create table user_master(id int not null auto_increment,name " + "varchar(25),city varchar(20), primary key(id));";
                        // execyteUpdate() mothod execute specified sql query.
                        statement.executeUpdate(QueryString);
                        out.print("QueryString");
        %>
        <TABLE>
            <TR>
                <TD align="center" >
                    <font size="+3" color="green">Congratulations !</font>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <tr>
                <TD align="center" >
                    <font size="+2">Table of specified name is created successfully.</font>
                </TD>
            </tr>

        <%      } catch (Exception ex) {%>
        </TABLE>
        <TABLE>
            <TR>
                <TD align="center" >
                    <font size="+3" color="red">Some problems to create table.</font>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <%
            }

            %>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" >
                    <A HREF="welcome_to_database_query.jsp">
                        <font size="5" color="blue">back to home page</font>
                    </A>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </TABLE>
</body>
```

I don't know whats wrong but it fails to connect. What I have already done:

- installed MYSQL server,
- restarted TOMCAT,
- done administrative Tools connect thing.

Comment: no need for `newInstance` in `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`

Comment: @JigarJoshi there is catch block in the program which gets executed....

Comment: @RanRag will try and tell plz wait .....

Comment: Try to pring exceptionStacktrace in that catch block and let us know

Comment: Thanks All But I found solution going to give that in answers :)

Comment: That's one hell of a nasty example. Scriptlets, Class.forName, direct access to the database from presentation layer... Hope it's just a one-time tutorial app ;-)

Comment: Aren't "answers" for answers and comments for... well, you know - "comments"? "Kids don't know but it works ;-)" it's not about "works" and "doesn't work". It's about good design, maintainability, extension, security, being less error prone, ... Chill out mate - it's for your own good ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Here the Solution to connect MYSQL with JSP above given program. I asked about to my boss, he is a real expert...

First open **Netbeans**

Click on **SERVICES** 
then Right Click on the server like for me its "Apache Tomcat" then select **Edit Server.XML**

Add below Line at line 39 i think between ***GlobalNamingResources*** tags

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DATABASENAME" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="4" maxIdle="2" username="root" password="" maxWait="23000" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASENAME"></Resource>
```

and Save it

Now select **Projects**

then right Click on the project you are working and select **Properties**

Now in **Libraries** Under Compile tab click **Add JAR**
Then locate your "mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar"

then click ok

then restart server

then Its Done !